# How to properly filter ArrayController

Tags: ember.js

I want to filter an existing ArrayController by a subproperty. How to do that? My filter does not work or is empty, as I don't see any items appear (and if i do not filter, i see them).

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**Models**

```
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    user: DS.belongsTo('user')
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    ...
});
App.User = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    status: DS.belongsTo('status'),
    ...
});
App.Status = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    techName: DS.attr('string')
});
```

**Controllers**

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    activeUsers: function() { 
        return this.filterBy('user.status.techName', 'active'); 
    }.property('@each','@each.user','@each.user.status','@each.user.status.techName')
 });
App.ActiveUsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['posts']
});
```

**Template**
(my active-users template)

```
<ul>
    {{#each controllers.posts.activeUsers}}
        <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ember.computed.filterBy` will satisfy your requirement.

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({ 
    activeUsers: Ember.computed.filterBy('content','user.status.techName','active'),  
 });
```

This is not documented yet, but you can learn from the comments in the source code [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/32f9d6bcc760907a901549e1e3a0791d971600e8/packages/ember-runtime/lib/computed/reduce_computed_macros.js#L250)

A sample [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/irItigE/1/edit)